# Angular Nested Forms Validations

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I would like to point out that I have been dealing with this issue for 1 month. I'm open to any suggestions.

I have form pages that receive input data from the user. These pages contain a component called basa-crud-page. This base-crud-page component uses Template Driven Forms and the codes inside look like this. The reason I cannot share the entire code is because it is the codes of the company I have just started working for:

```
<form #editForm="ngForm" validate>

      <ng-container *ngIf="customized">
        <ng-content select="[customForm]"></ng-content>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngIf="!customized">
        .
        .
        Here are the codes of the elements of the base form
        .
        .
      </ng-container>
</form>
```

The "customized" property on this page has a false value by default, and form validations work perfectly on my pages that use base-crud-page directly. For example for glr-vezne-pos-page there is a usage like this:

```
selector: 'glr-vezne-pos-page',
  template: `
    <ng-container>
      <base-crud-page #baseCrudPage />
    </ng-container>`
```

However, when I write a page with the customized property set to true and where I specify the form elements myself, the form controls never work.
As an example of its usage:

```
<ng-container>
  <base-crud-page [customized]="true">
    <div customForm>
    .
    .
    Here are the codes of the form elements of the "custom" form.
    .
    .
    </div>
  </base-crud-page>
</ng-container>
```

*Note: the div labeled customForm in this component must be placed in the `<ng-content select="[customForm]"></ng-content>` field in the base-crud-page.*

What I suspect is this:

I can print a page created as in the first example and the ngAfterViewInitte form to the console.

[image]

As in the second example, a page is created as a custom form and the form is not printed to the console. As you can see, 'Kaydet' - that is, the Save button seems to be active as the controls are not working.

[image]

I am open to all kinds of ideas and need help.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. You have an error in console, that say you "can not read properties
   of undefined" in meta-new-button.component.ts. So there you have a
   variable that you expect have value but it's not. You need check
   before

   ```
     if (my-variable)
        other-variable=my-variable.property
   ```
2. When we have "nested-forms" (the "form" is declared in the the
   parent) in a component, generally we use viewProvider. See that,as
   you're using Template Driven Forms, you useExisting: `ngForm` (not
   FormDirective)

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'base-crud-page',
     templateUrl: './base-crud-page.component.html',
     viewProviders:[{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
   })
   ```
3. Try first with a simple component with only a button and one input
   to check the problem is not in how you define your inputs

Comment: When I added viewProviders, this message show in console NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm!

Comment: @MerveTağcı, I just write an example in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ukbgty?file=src%2Fmain.ts), It's dificult for me imagine your question, can you fork the stackblitz and create another with a structure similar to your problem?